# Can I keep oil filter for longer?

Tags: oil, oil-change, oil-filter

I have 09 Altima with 135k miles and it now consumes way too much engine oil to the extent the oil was all gone for next service! So now I make sure to fill it with more oil every month.

My question is, can I use the oil filter for longer runs since roughly every 2 months, the oil is getting replaced.

Like should I keep the filter for 10k miles or even more?

When I do oil & filter change, I go with regular oil but as it consumes so much oil, the new oil I put in it are synthetic.

p.s I don't think there is an oil leak since I have never seen any leaks when the car is parked at home or work.

Answer (score 1):

No, the oil filter collects dirt and particles and needs to be changed at the specified intervals.

I used a much higher quality of oil in an engine and doubled the oil change interval **but** kept the filter change interval the same.

Comment: But the high mileage synthetic oil does use the same filter so technically it might be ok for longer runs? Even though changed yours early but please take notice I am not driving a Ferrari, its fairly old commuter car and I hope to get a couple of years more out of it.

Comment: I was using Mobil One 5W-50 (which seems to be hard to get now) and was very expensive back then. But it is up to you, I gave you good advice - up to you to ignore or use it as you wish. Just remember filters are cheap.

Comment: @zar - You didn't specify you were using a Mobil1 20k filter ... if you are, you probably want to adjust your question. Giving only part of the information and expecting an informative answer is like pulling a grapefruit out of an apple bin ... it *might happen*, but chances are you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the filter for 10k miles.  However, this is not where I would try to save money or time.  Oil filters cost less than $5 on Amazon (Fram PH6607).

With an engine that has over 100k miles, you should change the oil at whatever schedule the manufacturer recommends (my Altima schedule says every 3k miles).  If the oil is black before that point, you should change the oil early.

If you are leaking oil so bad that it is "all gone for the next service", you should be topping off the oil regularly.  **NEVER RUN AN ENGINE ON LOW OIL!**  This is one of the fastest ways to kill an engine.  I would recommend you check your oil every time you fill your gas tank.  You should buy a few quarts of oil to keep in the trunk.  If the oil level is ever below the low line on the dipstick, dump a quart of oil and re-check the level.

Comment: My oil is black two days after being changed - you seriously suggest it needs changing again?

Comment: You could use a filter for 100k miles, but is it a good idea? Absolutely not. IMHO, at the most, only use an oil filter from oil change to oil change and no further.

Comment: What Solar Mike said - unless you have a brand new engine, oil *should* look black (but not like black sludge) quickly, otherwise it isn't doing its job of cleaning the cylinder walls! I don't understand why the USA has a fixation with 3,000 mile oil changes either. Nissan UK recommends ***18,000*** miles, which is the typical number for European car makers.

Comment: @SolarMike Place a drop of oil on your windshield.  Can you see sunlight through it?  If not, change your oil.  If you can, it's not black yet.  If your oil is that black in 2 days, you might have bad piston rings.

Comment: @alephzero I was wrong, it's 3750 miles, not 3,000 miles: https://owners.nissanusa.com/content/techpub/common/2012/2012-nissan-service-maintenance-guide.pdf page 15

Answer (score 0):

Rather than focusing on how long you can use an oil filter, I'd strongly encourage you to find out where all the oil is going.

To answer the question you did ask, instead of the one you didn't, figuring out where the oil is going will help you understand how much "work" your filter is doing. If the oil is blowing out past seals while you're driving, there's no need to replace your filter more frequently than the "normal" change interval. But if you are burning the oil, you will need to replace the filter more often due to the additional contaminants in the oil from being burned and scraped back into the oil pan.

It isn't unusual for an engine to consume more oil over time. Determining if this is "normal wear and tear" versus something more drastic, such as a broken ring or damaged cylinder wall, should be obvious from your oil change records. But you must figure out what's going on before you can decide if you can let the oil filter go a bit longer.

Answer (score 0):

Simply keep it in as long as the manufacture recommends but be aware of your engine problem.

If you don't see any excessive visible smoke you might simply have a problem with PCV valve (positive crankshaft ventilation). They tend to bust over time and allow oil to be sucked into the manifold.

You might also have a internal engine problem such as worn piston rings. In such case keep in mind that more fuel will be wash down the cylinder wall carbonizing the oil quicker. Lack of lubrication will put extra strain and wear on the engine components creating fine particles that get usually trapped in the oil filter.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would consult your mechanic about checking to be sure you don't have a simple issue causing the oil consumption as others have suggested. If nothing simple is found my next suggestion would be to try an oil additive like "RESTORE", "MOTOR MEDIC", or a similar product. These are primarily viscosity enhancers. The oil is thick enough to not pass easily by worn rings, valve guides etc. I would switch to the cheapest conventional oil you can find. If you are using that much oil you are reaping none of the benefits of expensive synthetic oil. The key to keeping the motor running is to check the oil regularly. Every day if necessary. Keep it at the full mark of the dip stick but not above. At the least change the filter at the recommended intervals. The oil may not seem dirty, but the oil filter will get plugged with the sediment. Eventually the oil consumption will get so bad the plugs may foul with unburned oil. You can try anti foul adapters at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Since you replace the engine oil completely by topping it up between the oil changes, I would recommend the reverse:

Don't change the oil, just change the filter when your filter gets the manufacturer-proposed mileage. You will save more than by skipping the filter change and the oil change is pointless anyway.

Of course, such a high oil loss is a good hint that the engine needs fixing or replacement. You may be OK with running the car until it breaks and then throwing it away, but also be aware that the oil loss can only go up. Running an engine with low oil is a good method of breaking it quickly no matter what other problems the engine may or may not have.